# TS function to perform union narrowing given a value for a discriminant-like key

Tags: typescript

I am looking to build a function which can perform type narrowing on a union which acts as a discriminated union at runtime but is not of a discriminated union type in TypeScript.

I currently have this (simplified) code, but `props` inside the `if` statements always have the `WidgetPropsSet` type:

```
if (props.kind === "CheckboxInput") {
    console.log("We need to use", props, "here as its narrowed `CheckboxInput` type");
}
if (props.kind === "DropdownInput") {
    console.log("We need to use", props, "here as its narrowed `DropdownInput` type");
}
// ... 16 more
```

(the non-simplified version of this code is a Svelte template, so the structure shown above can't really be redesigned)

I am thinking that I could replace the `props.kind === "`*`discriminator`*`"` inside the if statement with a function (TS pseudo-code):

```
function narrowWidgetProps(props: WidgetPropsSet, kind: WidgetPropsNames): a-concrete-variant-from-WidgetPropsSet | undefined {
    if (props.kind === kind) return a-concrete-variant-from-WidgetPropsSet;
    else return undefined;
}
```

**How do I write this pseudocode function in proper TypeScript that can perform the needed narrowing?**

For context, these are the union variants I am dealing with:

```
abstract class WidgetProps {
    kind!: string;
}

class CheckboxInput extends WidgetProps {
    checked!: boolean;
    disabled!: boolean;
    // ...
}

class DropdownInput extends WidgetProps {
    entries!: string[];
    selectedIndex!: number | undefined;
    // ...
}
```

And here is the actual union, which needs to be in this `{ value, name }[]` format so `widgetSubTypes` can be fed to third-party code that needs it in that format.

```
const widgetSubTypes = [
    { value: CheckboxInput, name: "CheckboxInput" },
    { value: DropdownInput, name: "DropdownInput" },
    // ...
] as const;
// Evaluated type:
// const widgetSubTypes: readonly [{
//     readonly value: typeof CheckboxInput;
//     readonly name: "CheckboxInput";
// }, {
//     readonly value: typeof DropdownInput;
//     readonly name: "DropdownInput";
// }, ... 16 more ..., {
//     ...;
// }]

type WidgetPropsSet = InstanceType<typeof widgetSubTypes[number]["value"]>;
// Evaluated type:
// type WidgetPropsSet = CheckboxInput | DropdownInput | ... 16 more

type WidgetPropsNames = typeof widgetSubTypes[number]["name"];
// Evaluated type:
// type WidgetPropsNames = "CheckboxInput" | "DropdownInput" | ... 16 more
```

Here is a [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAkFEBkAVQHKUgEVaA6gSQCrlHlgMqgBiAqggMI5YDyCAXAFAjMBmArgHYDGALgEsA9t1DcAhgCcpwgO4ZBAEwDmAU36xZABwDOACm07djTMvWbjRDQBpQAa0Hclpxao1bhehBIC2a3QBKU2AAKgI6FDpTACU1bQAbCV41UDlBfgALcWlZOTUlUH4AT21U0LA3C089a35QMNBIBBQIqNAK0AAfUB4lNXYnAtAAb2ZQCdBBdlBDYwA6R2dQAF41hyclQNApDU4pMUacSOjQOMTk1PSsnJl5YZKyjrAjL10G8ObW4-aKgG5xpM1AldKldvx9mI+gMhkoAQBfVjAJHMVGoiQAI10-CkyXqvCSuneVQ8xlGgImSyUAEJTNipE4VAjUQSJETQFRMmpePYMcIAB5YbjaTj1NT8-hqZzE8ykt7kyagXhcnkFWmgPnCBJqCTcAGKpSCXSY7U00ya7W6-WTECgeb25iI5is9koHRKeTcIUisUSqVKGXuSzysaKqU4wQBdX0xkAbQAutaJqDtQICkL+vz1dxOL4MWopN1es4YdwCkmGmB7fNHWiWaJsWlZfwiJwMThSgFVqBYxTRqAAG4SBKcNSmTnc3kC72iuySfymABEE55fMFwtFi9A8JsfZGg+Ho9Mbq8HrkXo3-DnfjHoEXJ+0Z4vPq3O77turzHjoDZSob-ABW1ICHEcJElQpHjHJE-24Rt0iDVt207Ewdh1D1uASYoezGW1FV2CR0Mwg8R1vSDhBmFcp3XH1ALAPC0NEIj51vZcVSomd+EXWjtzsHC6MmfDCKwkCjyKTtyNAB8nw47j6IIxisOYpcpM9DiuOgnc7XtUAAEYADZQF8YRdi0+ZeOgxVq24+F41RSCzCDGpdDqbshWxXUUg7MoAB4yJmeCLEQryAljHM8wLeNY0XES1EXeMAD5uOAw8wIeTsWFteySWDWoNG7Si1w4osVPPIqemrXSDKM3Y7M7BzqmMHx-HeFYxLKCSAo0ILkNC3N8ykSLF2YuKkpE1KIPS6CsubJymq7VrWMnQrLy3Hp73dVSVqLCr9MM4y1DrZ1-yVNjlp9Nz+A81JWrLOQOVO6dL30QIAWVJbHvO2DLr4NRFk2btFtXD7N1eh7qNFC6rvmN7VUKVr2GHUFQfe8H+Ehn75kNY0MVNbsEZBNQASOr7QCUDbSsvdGUm7W7JPJ59RWegEydPTbPvcjGqQBkqGc45n6Y4qnfvDBl5p7RdSGEYRFzsRcACFpBG5gWcfNmIa+qGU25cCM3FbsAAYid4Y7Xj0bsAFkwMyeZcWcYRfGe0B4tAfX5gAVlAAB+E6UcFjWftAUwVekyn-ZSIm0WNknJDufIlAK4H6hu3J5Gypy5jeWWE9RxcXuYaZZhjvICmzjjtj4qYZgzvQ-uWNYFtLlby77KPdC1X6EmEFR9EXDBUjLB5hF6UEZduYv47BjjZa5Ezfwyd4i-uQoAANG59Ze2tivPFVb9v5k77vFywepdEyYROASQpMgkAdUiyVJl5h+wCg302CxKJsbhixhR9N3RobYgUPOiJW71EXnHHmRVk6xzTsYauuhZaQKbgCAu+hwEFCQT6ZutpUF-1rnDdY61WYUxfM3HeDY94Hx7n3cQahB7D1iteWOJdJ6XmngWVIc9+ALxTnHUAy9MGig3pBXOFZd7an3l3Hux9QCn3PpfUA19b5FC5PwrWaYlC635K-HQ78sLXGyN-X+Cx1E6xLPyYB0EdpVX2swIAA) where the single function at the top can be edited to solve this question.

Comment: @jcalz The code I provided was already complete (aside from a single irrelevant type in the `class DropdownInput` example which I've changed to a `string[]` now). And I think it's relatively minimal, without sacrificing too much context. I have updated the question with a TS Playground link where the function I'm looking to solve is readily editable. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm confused; `props` is not of a discriminated union type; shouldn't `CheckboxInput` and `DropdownInput` have strongly typed `kind` properties as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlL4xN)?  If not then the question seems to be about something other than a discriminated union.

Comment: Sorry about that @jcalz, I've updated the Playground link in the main post with this important line I'd forgotten, which now properly demonstrates a simplified version of the case I'm facing: `const props = Math.random() > 0.5 ? checkboxInputInstance : dropdownInputInstance;` Does that clear up your confusion?

Comment: Okay, now it's a union, but it's still not a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) which is a particular sort of data structure TS supports for narrowing.  Your union has no discriminant property; `kind` is just `string`.  Presumably at runtime you will make sure that `kind` can be used to discriminate the union members, but this is not encoded in the type system.

Comment: If I try to ignore the words "discriminated union" and press ahead I get [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NV7zZm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (although it would be nice if we replaced "discriminated union" with some other term). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, that does indeed fix the problem in both the playground and my actual code. You're right that it feels a little weird to call it a discriminated union but I didn't know what else to call it, because it's related to that concept but not precisely the textbook example of its syntax. I'd be happy to edit the question (or you can) before you answer to clarify its meaning and hopefully improve search result hits to benefit other future visitors. Please give me your suggestions about how best to describe any inaccuracies in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251020/discussion-between-keavon-and-jcalz).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251053/discussion-between-jcalz-and-keavon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) members would have [literal typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `kind` properties so that it would be a true [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and you would get the desired narrowing automatically without needing a helper function:

```
class CheckboxInput extends WidgetProps {
    declare checked: boolean;
    declare disabled: boolean;
    declare kind: "CheckboxInput" // <-- literal type
}

class DropdownInput extends WidgetProps {
    declare entries: string[];
    declare selectedIndex: number | undefined;
    declare kind: "DropdownInput" // <-- literal type
}

declare const props: CheckboxInput | DropdownInput;

if (props.kind === "CheckboxInput") {
    props.checked // props is automatically narrowed to CheckboxInput
}

if (props.kind === "DropdownInput") {
    props.entries // props is automatically narrowed to DropdownInput
}
```

---

But if you can't do that for some reason and need to leave the `kind` property type alone in each subclass, then we can write your `narrowWidgetProps()` function as follows:

```
const widgetSubTypes = [
    { value: CheckboxInput, name: "CheckboxInput" },
    { value: DropdownInput, name: "DropdownInput" },
] as const;

type WidgetSubTypes = typeof widgetSubTypes[number];
type WidgetKindMap = { [T in WidgetSubTypes as T["name"]]: InstanceType<T["value"]> };
/* type WidgetKindMap = {
    CheckboxInput: CheckboxInput;
    DropdownInput: DropdownInput;
} */
type WidgetPropsNames = keyof WidgetKindMap
type WidgetPropsSet = WidgetKindMap[WidgetPropsNames]


function narrowWidgetProps<K extends WidgetPropsNames>(props: WidgetPropsSet, kind: K) {
    if (props.kind === kind) return props as WidgetKindMap[K]
    else return undefined;
}
```

I'm using the definition of `widgetSubTypes` to generate `WidgetKindMap`, a helper type whose keys are the literal `kind` values (which together make up the `WidgetPropsNames` union) and whose values are the instance types of the corresponding subclasses of `WidgetProps` (which together make up the `WidgetPropsSet` union).

Then the `narrowWidgetProps()` function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the type of the `kind` parameter.  If this does not match the `kind` property of the `props` argument, then we return `undefined`.  If it *doeS* match, then we [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `props` is actually of the type `WidgetKindMap[K]` (an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) meaning "the value type of `WidgetKindMap` corresponding to the key of type `K`").

We need that assertion, `as WidgetKindMap[K]`, because the compiler has no reason to believe that matching `kind` properties could really narrow `props` to that type.  If it did think this, then `WidgetPropsSet` would already be a discriminated union and this endeavor would be unnecessary, as mentioned above.

Anyway, let's test it:

```
declare const props: WidgetPropsSet;

const narrowedCheckboxInput = narrowWidgetProps(props, "CheckboxInput");
if (narrowedCheckboxInput) {
    // const narrowedCheckboxInput: CheckboxInput | undefined
    narrowedCheckboxInput.checked
}

const narrowedDropdownInput = narrowWidgetProps(props, "DropdownInput");
if (narrowedDropdownInput) {
    // const narrowedDropdownInput: DropdownInput | undefined
    narrowedDropdownInput.entries
}
```

Looks good.  The return type of `narrowWidgetProps()` depends on the `kind` argument in the way you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AwAictysqOvQLAwcgVYSBBUGiQIWpICJsEyIqIFHpJ0GwVA3zvgibD-PE8liaBcwegAsiAMDwSh3y5kgOjXCpkFqXBfBILm3wtERLS-L8Bi+KwNSII5wyuS06FYJhnkAHxIJYi79AAVHJol2bcRm6KZ5myUGBSkb2MrYR0uU9He9Bsf6gQGKVFKLpYSBxf0elJeJx7yAAcuAcGyZoEBpopyUSKlaDpQ1sF9c1UBgRI8FNQN6XfE1NZQG1sa-DY8SYuiYJEFyhHqLIhzzfcwwLPuVwHbES3QBFKr8qNC0TSwBGEgYcyBtRzrXeqmo6p1HpmhoLD+GwwC8mOznTSZZnfHMK31iCD5IP9gPA+iGC-v+zKrZ2QFcJOQq4T0vksP5yCyX+hzdgV+OBEqJqLrjZEyoTxPuro8H6pTRqBC0dM4ZzLBM8AiA2nanqyZi2APjzHMUgLQulFA5TpPB4tYJLQmAQJKi+oxjMCcT8Fk0glUyjTi5oNr7EE3rgsQCzot6sbxpmxbZX89bQvnh1CEtAAYnOLQES0ABC6iec7pI61bfk22qD6gs+GJePBAAMcpY5rroGGd8j3fBplJmqHC6DIYA00gUXJ2qACsSAAPwpNLuvR4gSAGObEeW4EssQHKWzYztbB7ekOVU1wpO7Uc2dQB98iByPfOmou72gIPRzD7zFKvfWgzcP3K9D2g88UvleN81+KNYjiaDUfva+HxvMrC1O18Y+nPK34c6SO2c4+r-toELRnlAQO39ei03lIqJUH8v4u03qeZQO9+Lvwnp-NAoCKqwJlOfH8V8b4oJgR3V2oZgBvAjBjKMQA)